# Should I store external object ids (ids coming from REST server) using NSString or int32?

Tags: ios, core-data

NSString seems like the safest bet, but also the laziest. I don't know much about core date internals, so i'm not exactly sure what the performance benefits, if any, using indexed integer attribute over a indexed NSString attribute.

Comment: Will you be able to do lots of searching and sorting based on that ids? if yes then int32 is better,

Comment: I don't think so. I think most of the fetching/sorting will be based on NSDate attributes and then single record retrieval based on external id for ocasional updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions about performance are bad. Without proof, assumptions are worth nothing.

The database engine may well compare strings faster than int32 if it is implemented well, and string indexes also have the potential to be faster than int32 indexes. So not assume int32 will be faster overall.

Start with the easiest solution. Easiest means less bugs. Laziness is good.

Then use the profiler to see what eats CPU cycles and work on that. If the string-based lookups are an issue, try with int32 ids. Or the other way, whatever. The important word here is profiler.

Comment: This is totally wrong!!  Never ever a string compare is faster than an int32. This only could be faster if you make an unfair comparision, like compare an indexed table with String to an unindexed with int32.

Comment: Real life benchmarks taught me that "never ever" means everything in theory but nothing in practice. Feel free to think int32 are always faster if you like, I saw several times they weren't. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: No database engine will compare a string faster than an int. That could only be the case if you wrap the Integer into a string, or such silly things. In real life benchmarks you might measure evrything else , but not the compare operation

Comment: In real life, the compare operation worth nothing alone. It always take place in a query, rule or proc evaluation. I do not care (not true, but lets say I don't care) how the thing work, I do care how it performs, and to know how it performs I profile it instead of making assumptions. You should do the same.